# Combine WCF Services

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I have two WCF services. Both of them have a pair of Class.cs and IClass.cs files (class and interface).

Now I want to create someway a new interface which will inherit all the operations from the initial two interfaces and expose them as one. Can I do this with C# (.NET 4.0)?

I have read something about WCF routing service. Is that the only solution?

Comment: you can create a common interface `public interface ICommon : Class1, IClass2 {}` but do you really need that? Can you describe the reason of exposing this interfaces as one?

Comment: I have 10 interfaces on the server side and I'm trying to avoid to create 10 different WCF client objects on the client. Is there another way to do that? What I want, is to call all the server operations via a single WCF client.

Comment: Are you using [add service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) or you just create client objects manually?

Comment: Can I have multiple interfaces with multiple implementations exposed from a single endpoint?

Comment: I am using add service reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do single wcf client by implementing class which could have as many [channel factories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) as services, but it will create to heavy object with too big responsibility.

If you want only one class to calling services you can try creating [generic service proxy](http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/creating-a-wcf-service-proxy-with-channelfactory/).
Example of usage:

```
using (var proxy = new ServiceProxy<IClass1>())
{
  proxy.Channel.Foo();
}
```